# error al importar tensorflow en visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

instale tensorflow con pip pero
al correr el codigo me arroja lo siguiente:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

es un error de importacion pero no se porque si
la importacion la hice de acuerdo a la documentacion.

import tensorflow as tf

Comment: Está VSCode usando el python donde está tf?

Comment: no sabria decirte apenas empiezo con esto. como lo compruebo?

Comment: Si estás usando vscode en la [parte inferior en la barra de estado](https://ibb.co/gMmn4HM) muestra la versión del intérprete que estás usando y puedes seleccionar entre diferentes versiones.

Comment: amigo dios te bendiga me funciono. cambie de version basado en lo que dijiste y listo,